# Reporting Services: make room for long value in a field

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm struggling with Reporting Services to get this done.

I have several reports with a common header which contains some contact info, including e-mail address and web address. If those get too long, they right now just overwrite the data in the next cell below them - which is really really ugly...

So I have a report header something like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                         T I T L E                           |
|                                                             |
| Name                            E-Mail:  (value of e-mail)  | 
| Address                         Web Url: (value of web url) |
| Zip City                                                    |
|                                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Those fixed texts ("E-Mail" and "Web Url") are standard Textfields, as are the value field, bound to a set of data that my reports gets from my ASP.NET application. These values (on the right of the header) are contained inside a single "Rectangle" that basically groups everything on the right together.

But if the e-mail is really long, what I'd like to do is "slide" the "Web Url:" label and value down one line, if the e-mail is really long - like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                         T I T L E                           |
|                                                             |
| Name                            E-Mail:  (really really long| 
| Address                                   value of e-mail)  |
| Zip City                        Web Url: (value of web url) |
|                                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But somehow, no matter what I try, I can't get this behavior :-( The Textfield for the e-mail value has its `CanGrow` property set to true and the contents of the e-mail does extend down into the next line - but there it just overwrites the string value in the "web url" value field....

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to work when testing here - http://imgur.com/9JeCKBR,UODv4gs#0 http://imgur.com/9JeCKBR,UODv4gs#1 so is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@benni_mac_b was right - if the output fields are properly aligned and separated, Reporting Services itself will handle this situation just fine.

In my case, I had ever so slightly overlapping output fields, and for some reason, that seems to have prevented the usual growth of a line and caused the line below to be "overprinted".

I carefully separated those output fields - made sure their height was less than their distance in position, and now it works just fine.